# Android DiskLruCache.java

Tags: android, caching, android-sdcard

What is **valueCount** here,when it is useful?,Any real time example will be helpful.

```
private DiskLruCache(File directory, int appVersion, int valueCount, long maxSize) {
    this.directory = directory;
    this.appVersion = appVersion;
    this.journalFile = new File(directory, JOURNAL_FILE);
    this.journalFileTmp = new File(directory, JOURNAL_FILE_TMP);
    this.valueCount = valueCount;
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: did you read the documentation?

Comment: yes, but i cannot understand, any example please..

Comment: Cache is working only for valueCount=1, but in documentation they said it must be positive number